# Marketing Cloud Ampscript add and group by fields

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, aggregate, sum

Looking to add the Cost here and grouped by OrderId and purchaseNumber. I have the below but I think it is incorrect. I have other fields in the Data Extension but want the sum of cost aggregated by OrderId and purchaseNumber.

```
set @rows = LookupRows(@orderDE,  "OrderID", @OrderID,  "purchaseNumber", @purchaseNumber, "cost", @Cost)

Set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows)
  
IF @rowCount >= 1 then 
   set @totalCost = 0

   FOR @i = 1 TO @rowCount DO 
      SET @columns = Row(@rows,@i) 
      SET @OrderID = Field(@columns, "OrderID")
      SET @purchaseNumber = Field(@columns, "purchaseNumber")
      SET @Cost = Field(@columns, "Cost") 
      set @totalCost = add(@totalCost, @Cost)
```

Comment: You've got an extra comma after orderID.

Why do you need to add Cost to totalCost if totalCost is set to 0?  Wouldn't the total cost always be @Cost?

In  that case you might want to use Lookup to obtain the Cost variable vs Lookuprows with the for loop

Comment: Thank you. I see what you are saying. Looking for the code on how to sum up based on those grouping fields.

Comment: What is the problem are you facing?